# Greater part of decimal number in js

Tags: javascript

I have this problem:

Write a function *greaterpart* that receives a decimal number. The number should be greater than zero.
The function is required to identify the bigger part of the decimal number, whether it’s the integer or
the fractional part, and then alert the bigger part.
For example:

`greaterpart(32.45)` alerts **45**.
and
`greaterpart(301.71)` alerts **301**.

And this is my solution:

```
function graterpart(x){
  if(x<0){
    alert("Number can not be null");
  }

  else{
    var x;
    var y;
    y= parseFloat(x);
    var remainder = (y-Math.floor(y))*10000;
    if(y>remainder){
      alert(y);
    } else{
      alert(remainder);
    }
  }
}
graterpart(32.45);
```

But it is not working as it should be.
What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if(x<1)` should be

Comment: Side note: did you know that JavaScript has a [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_())?

Comment: i also spot a duplicate named variable `x` (parameter and inside else)

Comment: You multiply by 10000, so your .45 gets a 4500...

Comment: Ok but it is still not working it is not solving my problem

Comment: Simple convert it to string split by . get two element array parseInt each and compare simplest of all

Comment: By definition the part after the decimal point is always smaller. You really just have two numbers separated by a `.` character, the way you're treating them…

Comment: can you please show me snippet of code how to do it ? I am beginner in javascript

Comment: `x<0` does not means a number is `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
function greaterpart(x){
    alert(Math.max.apply(this, x.toString().split('.')));
}
greaterpart(32.45);
</script>
```

Math.max() will implicitely convert the strings returned by String.prototype.split() into numbers.

If you don't understand the function reformulate it with distinct steps:

Turn the number into a string:

```
x = x.toString();
```

Split it at the decimal point:

```
var parts = x.split('.');  // Is now ["32", "45"]
```

Get the maximum value:

```
var greater = Math.max(parts[0], parts[1]);
```

But there is a shorter way.  Keep this in mind:

```
var result1 = fun(arg1, arg2, arg3);
var result2 = fun.apply(thisValue, [arg1, arg2, arg3]);
```

The second line looks a little convoluted but does exactly the same as the first.  You can use this now to simplify the call to Math.max():

```
var greater = Math.max.apply(this, parts);
```

And now output it with console.log() or alert().

Answer (score 3):

Simple convert it to string split by . get two element array parseInt each and compare simplest of all

```js
var s = 56.69;
//console.log(s.toString())
var d = s.toString().split(".");

var greater = (parseInt(d[0],10) > parseInt(d[1],10)) ? d[0] : d[1];

alert(greater);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can simply be done like this:

```
 var number = 312.25;

 var numberStr = number.toString();

 var twoParts = numberStr.split(".");

 if ((parseInt(twoParts[0])) > (parseInt(twoParts[1]))){ 
     alert (twoParts[0]);
 }else {
     alert(twoParts[1]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best will be to convert your decimal to string and then split it by ".", convert both parts to integer and alert the greater part.

```
function graterpart(x){
  if(x < 0){
        alert("Number can not be null");
  }else{
    var str = x.toString();
    if(str.indexOf(".") != -1){
      var parts = str.split(".");
      var first_part = parseInt(parts[0]);
      var second_part = parseInt(parts[1]);

      alert(Math.max(first_part, second_part));
    }else{
        alert(x);
    }
  }
}
graterpart(321.45);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x7on7xjk/